# what are the ways to insert javascript to an existing pdf file (via API)

Tags: javascript, pdf, sdk, adobe

I was trying to find out any entries in the Adobe's API giving functionality of injecting javascript into the pdf file, but I couldn't find anything. I saw that there are few open source libraries that do that, but I'd like to focus on Adobe's SDK (C/C++).

Are there any ways to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: PDFs can speak JS? What is the world coming to....

Comment: Yep, PDFs have been speaking JS for a number of years now.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, as you've discovered you can find a third party PDF library that will let you insert JavaScript into PDFs or you can use Adobe's PDF library SDK. You'll find all of the info that you need in the [Acrobat Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html). There is also this useful article: [Introduction to Acrobat JavaScript](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/learningcenter.asp?ContainerID=1519).